# Submit button not consistently firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an asp.net core razor form with a submit button.  When the user clicks 'Update', the form calls a JavaScript function to prompt the user if they are sure they want to complete the request.  This functionality has been working, but starting last week, the form will occasionally not save despite the user confirming that they want to complete the request.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Requests.Complete" class="lblReq"></label>
    <select id="isComplete" asp-for="Requests.Complete" class="inputReq switch-disable">
        <option value="N">N</option>
        <option value="Y">Y</option>
    </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Requests.Complete" class="text-danger"></span>
</div> 

   
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return CompleteOrNot()" />
</div>


@section Scripts {
@{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
    function CompleteOrNot() {
        var value = ($("#isComplete").val());            
        if (value == "Y")
        {
            var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to complete this request?");
            window.history.go(-1);                
            if (retVal == true) {                    
                return true;
            }                
        }                   
    }
}
```

The user always gets prompted if they want to complete the request and sometimes the post goes through and other times it acts as though the user said no to the prompt (even though they did not).  Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot/correct this issue?

Comment: Never worked with ASP before, so can't really help you with proper code. However, going back in the browser's history is definitely the wrong approach here and most likely the cause of your issue. Instead, you should use jQuery to catch the form submit: `$("#your_form_id_here").submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`. The preventDefault will prevent the form being submitted. Then just pop up a modal or something for confirmation and have the yes button [pull all form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and submit it.

Comment: `window.history.go(-1);` <-- why are you going back on a form submission??? Does not make sense why you are doing that. You have the browser wanting to submit a form and you have the code telling it to go back in history.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback.  An admin is monitoring a queue of requests and when they click 'edit' on the row, it redirects the current window to the edit page, and then the window.history.go(-1) takes them back to the queue page.  Perhaps I should just open the edit page in a new window instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to submit the form when `retVal` is true,try to use the following code

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Requests.Complete" class="lblReq"></label>
    <select id="isComplete" asp-for="Requests.Complete" class="inputReq switch-disable">
        <option value="N">N</option>
        <option value="Y">Y</option>
    </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Requests.Complete" class="text-danger"></span>
</div> 


    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="button" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="CompleteOrNot()" />
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CompleteOrNot() {
            var value = ($("#isComplete").val());
            if (value == "Y") {
                var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to complete this request?");
                if (retVal == true) {
                    $("#myForm").submit();
                }
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {

            
        })

    </script>
}
```